# Why does Islam trace its origins to Abraham?

Tags: history, islamic-philosophy, prophet-ibrahim

I have learned [Islam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam) traces its origins to [Abraham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_in_Islam), I wonder why he is considered the 'first Muslim'?

Comment: Curious as to where the idea of Abraham as the first Muslim comes from, skimmed over the Wikipedia article and found nothing suggesting that but I maybe wrong. To my knowledge, Adam was considered the first Muslim. Due to in Islam people are considered to be born Muslim by nature. (7:172-173)

Comment: You should explain why do you think Abraham is considered the first Muslim or what is your backup for this? Do you have any suggestion why Islam would trace its origins to Abraham? What efforts have you done before asking this question which seems to include some flaws?

Comment: I have come across this knowledge while reading the Role of Islam in Judeo-Christianity [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judeo-Christian#Role_of_Islam).

Comment: There are certainly a lot of reasons one could think of. For example just think of anything related to hajj all of that has a clear relation to Ibrahim pbuh, his wife Hajar etc.. Also Muhammad pbuh has a direct lineage to Ismael the son of Ibrahim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, **[Adam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_in_Islam) is considered the first Muslim** by Muslims. This is because Adam is called a prophet of God and the Quran also says that all the prophets are of the same faith (Islam). It is [Abraham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_in_Islam) who is considered to have built the first house of worship on Earth. All that being said, there are **multiple verses in the Quran that suggest that Muhammad was truly the first Muslim**, such as surah 6:163 and 39:11-12.

So neither Wikipedia nor the Quran seem to suggest that Abraham was considered the first Muslim, though he is highly regarding as a prophet and is important in the text.